# PHP call external function in class

Tags: php, oop

I have simple function say

```
function ABC()
{
     //Somecode;
    return $a;

}
```

and i have class

```
class XYZ {

}
```

What i want to do is call function ABC in class XYZ and assign return value to some variable in class XYZ and use there like :

```
class XYZ {

  $var = ABC();
}
```

Comment: Do it in the constructor.

Comment: @mario That doesnt answers my question.

Comment: Why doesn't it?

Comment: @mario i want to call external function in class and use return value inside class, that question shows calling function thats also inside class

Comment: That doesn't make a difference; neither syntactically nor how to approach it. Btw, there's a few more duplicates that already cover this.